# inserting tweets in MONGODB

Tags: php, mongodb, twitter

```
<?php
require 'app_tokens.php';
require 'tmhOAuth-master/tmhOAuth.php';
$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
    'user_token' => $user_token,
    'user_secret' => $user_secret
));
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->twitter;
$collection = $db->tweets;
$screen_name = "learnmongo";
$http_code = $connection->request('GET', $connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'));
if ($http_code == 200) {
    $twitter = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?";
    $curl = curl_init($twitter);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $usertimeline = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $usertimeline = json_decode($usertimeline);
    foreach ($usertimeline as $id => $item) {
        $collection->insert($item);
    }
}
```

now i have tried this code.it displays just a blank page.no error message is printed but tweets are not added in mondodb.can you tell why is it so??

Comment: What do you have in `$usertimeline` before entering a loop?

Comment: OK. What gets returned from `$collection->insert($item);`? `var_dump` it to check this precisely.

Comment: var_dump returns "null" .... what is the solution for my problem.?

Comment: The solution is to debug your code, find a bug and fix it. `var_dump($collection->insert($item);)` returns nothing all the time, it should instead print something to stdout. If it prints nothing then it does not execute. Maybe `$http_code` is not 200? Maybe your PHP dies, while hiding errors from you?

Comment: ohkkk let me see to it.thanx for your suggestions.but may i know whether my code is right or not?

Comment: // Handle errors from API request
else
    {
        if ($http_code == 429) 
          {
              print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
          }
       else 
         {
             print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that request';
         }
}......after adding these lines in the code it gives an error message as twitter was not able to process your request

Comment: I don't understand your logic with `$connection->request` and then `curl*`.

Comment: then what kindoff logic you will suggest?